# Different footers on two separate pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC4, I want to display footer with different contents on two different pages, to achieve this functionality which will be suitable, sections or any better solution ?

Comment: If the two footers are different and they are only used on two pages, why worry about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems pretty straight forward.

Layout.cshtml (whatever you called it)

```
<html>
<body>

  <div id="bodyContent">
    // content
    @RenderBody()
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
  @if (IsSectionDefined("customFooter")) // optional
  {    
    @RenderSection("customFooter")
  }
  else // optional
  {
    <div> standard footer </div>
  }
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All pages without customFooter will render standard footer.

Page With Footer 1

```
@Section customFooter
{
  <div>Custom Footer 1</div>
}
```

Page With Footer 2

```
@Section customFooter
{
  <div>Custom Footer 2</div>
}
```

This allows you to place the footer anywhere in the layout, and not just at the bottom of the RenderBody().